# How would you solve this geometry problem? (MMC $2015$)

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> **Question:** Find the area of the shaded region given $EB=2,CD=3,BC=10$ and $\angle EBC=\angle BCD=90^{\circ}$.

[image: Diagram]

I first dropped an altitude from $A$ to $BC$ forming two cases of similar triangles. Let the point where the altitude meets $BC$ be $X$. Thus, we have$$\triangle BAX\sim\triangle BDC\\\triangle CAX\sim\triangle CEB$$
Using the proportions, we get$$\frac {BA}{BD}=\frac {AX}{CD}=\frac {BX}{BC}\\\frac {CA}{CE}=\frac {AX}{EB}=\frac {CX}{CB}$$
But I'm not too sure what to do next from here. I feel like I'm *very* close, but I just can't figure out $AX$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: From the given info, you can compute the sum of the areas of triangles $\triangle EBC$ and $\triangle BDC$: 
$$
\frac{1}{2}(2\cdot 10)+\frac{1}{2}(3\cdot 10)=25.
$$
With a quick observation, you can also compute the sum of the areas of triangles $\triangle EBA$ and $\triangle ACD$:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(2\cdot4)+\frac{1}{2}(3\cdot6)=13.
$$
Two times the answer you seek is the difference between these 2 sums.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$\frac {BA}{BD} = \frac {BE}{BE + CD}$ because $\triangle AEB\sim\triangle ACD$

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates:

B (0,0)

E(0,2)

C (10, 0)

D( 10, 3)

BD  10y - 3x = 0

EC x+5y = 10

Find y coordinate of A:
10y - 3x = 0, 3x+15y = 30 => 25y = 30 => y = 6/5

Area size is 10*(6/5)/2 = 6;

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just add the right hand pairs of equations you have so you get $$\frac{AX}{CD}+\frac{AX}{EB}=1$$

Substituting the values, you get $AX=\frac 65$ so the required area is...?

Comment: $[ABC]=\frac 65\cdot 10/2=6$

Comment: Yes that's it!.